# Django: Aggregating Across Submodels Fields

Tags: python, django

I currently have the following models, where there is a `Product` class, which has many `Ratings`. Each `Rating` has a `date_created` DateTime field, and a `stars` field, which is an integer from 1 to 10. Is there a way I can add up the total number of stars given to all products on a certain day, for all days?

For instance, on December 21st, 543 stars were given to all Products in total (ie. 200 on Item A, 10 on Item B, 233 on Item C). On the next day, there might be 0 stars, because there were no ratings for any Products.

I can imagine first getting a list of dates, and then filtering on each date, and aggregating each one, but this seems very intensive. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it all in one query, using `values`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from django.db.models import Sum

end_date = date.now()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=7)

qs = Rating.objects.filter(date_created__gt=start_date, date_created__lt=end_date)
qs = qs.values('date_created').annotate(total=Sum('stars'))

print qs
```

Should output something like:

```
[{'date_created': '1-21-2013', 'total': 150}, ... ]
```

The SQL for it looks like this (WHERE clause omitted):

```
SELECT "myapp_ratings"."date_created", SUM("myapp_ratings"."stars") AS "total" FROM "myapp_ratings" GROUP BY "myapp_ratings"."date_created"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Django's [aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/); specifically, [`Sum`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum).

```
>>> from django.db.models import Sum
>>>
>>> date = '2012-12-21'
>>> Rating.objects.filter(date_created=date).aggregate(Sum('stars'))
{'stars__sum': 543}
```

As a side note, your scenario actually doesn't need to use any submodels at all. Since the `date_created` field and the `stars` field are both members of the `Rating` model, you can just do a query over it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just perform some raw SQL:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT date_created, SUM(stars) FROM yourapp_rating GROUP BY date_created')
result = cursor.fetchall()  # looks like [('date1', 'sum1'), ('date2', 'sum2'), etc]
```